# Texto do button não fica alinhado

Tags: html, css, button

Quero saber como arrumar o texto dentro do button, já tentei criar um style no texto porém isso não funcionou.

```css
.buttonfunc button{

   font-family: 'Darker Grotesque';
   background-color: 7FBCB1;
   color: black;
   width: 150px;
   height: 35px;
   margin-top: 1.5rem;
   margin-left: 4rem;
   border-radius: 10px;
   font-size: 30px;
   padding: 8px;
   border: none;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonfunc"><button type="submit" name="confirmar">Enviar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá ana, explique melhor o que é "arrumar". É  centralizar, diminuir fonte ou outra coisa?

Comment: Ah sim, perdão. Seria centralizar ele.

Answer (score 0):

caso você queira que o botão fique do tamanho do texto, a alteração que precisa ser feita é no width e height, tem que ser auto assim:

```
width: auto;
height: auto;
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Isso alinha o botão conforme o texto, eu quero mexer no texto do jeito que eu quero que fique.

Comment: ah então altere o padding para padding: auto;

Comment: Usei o height: auto; mesmo. Pelo menos o texto fica alinhado no meio, obrigada.

Answer (score 0):

a forma correta de alinhar o texto no style é:

```
<div class="buttonfunc" style="text-align:center"><button type="submit" name="confirmar">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).